# What is the Elasticsearch equivalent of a negated 'LIKE' or CONTAINS' statement?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to do the Elasticsearch equivalent of the following SQL statement:

> SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName NOT LIKE '%something%'

I don't care about efficiency or scoring... This only gets executed on occasion. I am using request body syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a normal [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html), and negate it using a [bool must_not query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

```
GET Users/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [{
                "wildcard": {
                    "UserName": {
                        "value": "*something*"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your Users are your index in you Elastic - but this is the main idea anyway:
You could go with the `regexp` query by using `Complement - "~"` for negation:

```
GET Users/_search
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "UserName": {
                "value": ".*~(something).*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more useful reference, you can check [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/query-dsl-regexp-query.html)
**P.S:**
You will not get the best performance but it will do the job

Comment: I see from the documentation that query should work. However, it is not working for me so perhaps I have misconfigured something. Even if I do `"value": "*"` it is not returning any results which is strange because I have 1000-2000 documents in the index.

Comment: I hope once you will figure out the root of your problem, my answer would help. Good luck!